# Articulation Point of undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

Does the type and number of articulation points vary when the entry point(root node) changes for an undirected graph?

If it changes then why does that happen?

I do understand that points might vary but why does the number of points vary?

Here is my graph :-

[image: Graph]

Comment: put `!` mark before `[Graph][1]` like this `![Graph][1]`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component), articulation point is a vertex such that if it's removed than the number of connected components increases. There is nothing about entry points and DFS here: the definition depends only on the graph itself.

So, the answer to your question is: no, articulation points should not change if you traverse the graph from different nodes.

If you use a standard DFS-based algorithm to find articulation points, most likely you have a bug.

Comment: What i fail to understand in articulation point is the root node should have two independent child. In my graph as stated above, why is A(root) is not considered a cut vertex/articulation point.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov has answered this pretty clearly. Removing A (along with its incident edges) doesn't affect the number of connected components, so it's not an articulation point. Articulation points have nothing to do with graph roots or lack thereof.